# How do I call path in xml in c#. Can I use deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml, file, path, deserialization

I have two source files and I want to call their paths. This code wrote .ini but I have to use .xml. How can I write?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetPrivateProfileString(string kategori, string anahtar, string lpDefault, StringBuilder sb, int sbKapasite, string dosyaAdi);
static string FileName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\settings.xml";
string Path1 = ReadIni("PathLocation", "SourceFile1");
string Path2 = ReadIni("PathLocation", "SourceFile2");
```

Comment: You can use *XmlDocument* object to load xml file to it ex:
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("FilePath");

Comment: Or you can use Linq to XML... var xDoc = XDocument.Load("FilePath");

Comment: I tried them but it caused different problem all codes. This usage is not integrated with my codes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snipit of something I've used in a seperate project. Hope this works for you.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

string[] settingsDataOne;
string[] settingsDataTwo;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

//Load XML Doc #1
doc.Load("settings1.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/locations/inner");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    var id = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
    var name = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
    settingsDataOne = { id, name };
}

//Load XML Doc #2
doc.Load("settings2.xml")
nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/locations/inner");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    var id = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
    var name = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
    settingsDataTwo = { id, name };
}
```